# Output a row from MySql table using PHP with no extra information

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have recently started to learn MySQL and PHP, need some help. I need to take a row from a database and display only a content of cells.
Current code looks something like this:

```
$res = R::getAll("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID=5");
echo json_encode($res);
```

As I see it, I took the query and wrote its result into the variable $res, which I then printed using the function json_encode()

The result came out to be something like this:

> [{"ID":"5","name":"Falcon","price":"166.00"}]

But my intention was to get something like that:

> 5, Falcon, 166.00

Please help to get rid of unnecessary information in the form of column names and extra symbols.

Comment: did you try without json_encode ?

Answer (score 1):

```php
$res = R::getAll("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID=5");
echo implode(', ',$res[0]); // 5, Falcon, 166.00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = R::getAll("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ID=5");
$output = "";
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    $output = $output.$value.", ";
}
$output = substr($output, 0, -2);
echo $output;
```

Ouput: `5, Falcon, 166.00`